# How to reverse proxy call in apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setup as follows in Apache:

Server A with address `www.proxyserver.com/graphql` is the reverse proxy server. (magento - php)

It maps to: Server B with address `example.com` (reactjs)

This kind works properly while running in debug mode (`npm run start`).

For e.g: when server call a request `/graphql?query1=query1&query2=query2` then it redirects to `https://proxyserver.com/graphql?query1=query1&query2=query2`

But in apache, it doesn't work. It calls `http://example.com/graphql?query1=query1&query2=query2`

How do I fix this?

My reverse proxy is configured as follow on Server B ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/build
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/graphql" "https://proxyserver.com/graphql"
    ProxyPassReverse "/graphql" "https://proxyserver.com/graphql"
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is server A configuration

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@arrowhitech.com
        DocumentRoot /etc/pub
        ServerName proxyserver.com
        ErrorLog logs/cezanno-error_log
        LimitRequestBody 104857600
        <Proxy "unix:/var/opt/remi/php73/run/php-fpm/php73-fpm.sock|fcgi://proxyserver.com">
            ProxySet timeout=100
        </Proxy>
        <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://proxyserver.com"
        </FilesMatch>

        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/directory/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert/directory/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/cert/directory/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You say that, "_This kind works properly in develop environment_" but then you you say that, "_in apache, it doesn't work_". Surely development and production environments are both using Apache?

Comment: no, in develop environment, I just simply use `npm run start` to run, not use apache or any web servers to run it

Comment: The way you've written "_This kind works properly in develop environment._" implies that what you have described to us works in the development environment but does not work in production. If your environments are different please take the time to explain this in your question

Comment: I've just edited the original post. I mean `develop environment` is using command `npm run start` to run it

Comment: When you say "calls" do you mean proxies through to? Can you be clear on what you expect it to do? IE if you point curl at your server A, you aren't expecting a redirect but a direct response proxied from server B?